# Asignar un valor por defecto a una lista select en ASP.Net MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5, datos

Tengo una vista Edit la cual recibe datos de un Id seleccionado al querer llenar mis elementos de mi vista Edit con los datos correspondientes existe un select estático que muestra el valor inicial de la lista (lista de dos elementos), yo quisiera que mostrara en la lista el valor correspondiente al Id mandado

```
   <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TipoIngreso, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <select class="form-control" id="TipoIngreso" name="TipoIngreso">
            <option value="1">Comprado</option>
            <option value="2">Arrendado</option>
        </select>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TipoIngreso, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TipoIngreso, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

    @if (Model.TipoIngreso == 1)
    {
        <select class="form-control" id="TipoIngreso" name="TipoIngreso" tabindex=model.TipoIngreso>
            <option value="1" selected>Comprado</option>
            <option value="2">Arrendado</option>
        </select> }
    else
    {
        <select class="form-control" id="TipoIngreso" name="TipoIngreso" tabindex=model.TipoIngreso>
            <option value="1">Comprado</option>
            <option value="2"selected>Arrendado</option>
        </select>
    }
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TipoIngreso, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```